# как сделать комментарии к посту в django

Tags: python, django

Как я понимаю мне нужно сначала создать сами формы в forms.py, затем написать код в views.py и потом вывести его в шаблон поста. 
Если пользователь написал комментарий, то без проверки, комментарий сразу должен выводиться на страницу.
Я пытался исп. этот код с офф.документации django, но я так и не понимаю, как сделать, чтобы он выводился на страницу:

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms

class NameForm(forms.Form):
    your_name = forms.CharField(label='Your name', max_length=100)
```

**views.py**

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import render

from .forms import NameForm

def get_name(request):
    # if this is a POST request we need to process the form data
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # create a form instance and populate it with data from the request:
        form = NameForm(request.POST)
        # check whether it's valid:
        if form.is_valid():
            # process the data in form.cleaned_data as required
            # ...
            # redirect to a new URL:
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/thanks/')

    # if a GET (or any other method) we'll create a blank form
    else:
        form = NameForm()

    return render(request, 'name.html', {'form': form})
```

**html**

```
<form action="/your-name/" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Я использую миксин:

```
#utils.py

    class ObjectDetailMixin:
        model = None
        template = None

        def get(self, request, slug):
            obj = get_object_or_404(self.model, slug__iexact=slug)
            return render(request, self.template, context={self.model.__name__.lower(): obj, 'admin_object': obj, 'detail': True})
```

Во **views.py** у меня это:

```
class PostDetail(ObjectDetailMixin, View):
    model= Post
    template = 'main/post_detail.html'
```

Comment: А какие-нибудь модели у вас уже есть (models.py), покажите?

Comment: У меня нет моделей для контактной формы

Comment: По идее, нужны модели. Тогда во время `POST` запроса вы будете сохранять введенное имя в базу данных, делать редирект (на ту же страницу, например) и уже во время `GET` запроса вытягивать данные из БД и отображать их на странице. Вы совсем не знакомы с моделями?

Comment: Недавно начал изучать django

Comment: Вы случайно не знаете, где можно взять рабочий код этих комментариев и подстроить под себя?

Comment: Ответил, попробуйте воспроизвести.

Answer (score 1):

Для начала нужно создать простую модель:

```
# models.py

from django.db import models


class Name(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

Сделать миграции:

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```

Для формы проще использовать [ModelForm](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/forms/modelforms/), который нужен для создания форм из моделей

```
# forms.py    

from django.forms import ModelForm
from .models import Name


class NameForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Name
        fields = ('name',)
```

Во время POST запроса сохраняем введенное имя в базу данных, делаем редирект на ту же страницу, во время GET запроса вытягиваем данные из БД и отображаем их на странице.

```
# views.py

from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import render

from .forms import NameForm
from .models import Name


def get_name(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':

        form = NameForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            # Сохранение формы
            form.save()

            # Редирект на ту же страницу
            return HttpResponseRedirect(request.path_info)

    else:
    # метод GET

        form = NameForm()

        # Получение всех имен из БД.
        names = Name.objects.all()

    # И добавляем names в контекст, чтобы плучить к ним доступ в шаблоне
    return render(request, 'name.html', {'form': form, 'names': names})
```

Шаблон **name.html**

```
<form action="" method="post">
  {% csrf_token %}

  {% if names %}
    {% for name in names %}
      {{ name.name }}<br>
    {% endfor %}
  {% endif %}

  {{ form }}
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: А что, если я использую миксины (добавил код в теме), то получается 
код из вашего views.py нужно добавить в этот миксин?

Comment: То есть у вас Class-Based Views. Тогда мой пример с представлением в виде функции не подойдет, там совсем другой подход.

Comment: Какой подход, можете помочь, мучаюсь уже целый день

Comment: Я думаю вам нужно разобраться что такое Class-Based Views и как они работают. Поищите какие-нибудь статьи на эту тему. Вот эта вроде бы неплохая https://rayed.com/posts/2018/05/django-crud-create-retrieve-update-delete/ Представления показаны в двух вариантах - классы и функции.

Comment: Почему в вашу функцию views.py нельзя изменить на класс?

Comment: Изменить - не то слово. Вы можете добиться того же результата, с помощью представлений в виде классов. Например, с помощью CreateView для создания и ListView для вывода списка имен.

Comment: Получается, сначала я пишу миксин, затем объявляю класс в представлении. Но как его потом вывести? Для этого нужно создавать новый url, чтобы в нем передать этот класс? Не понимаю

Comment: Я так понял, что мы создаем миксин для того, чтобы следовать pep8

Comment: И облегчить код

Comment: Посмотрите статью, что я постил выше, там для каждого представления создается свой url. Для создания, удаления и отображения свое представление. Миксины нужны, если вы хотите переопределить какой-то метод (в вашем случае get) и потом использовать этот миксин в разных классах. К pep8 это отношения не имеет, но да, это нужно для того, чтобы не переопределять этот метод во всех классах, а просто наследовать из миксина.

Comment: Сижу уже 5 день, не могу разобраться. Прочитал статью, пробовал переделать ваш вариант, создав новый миксин и в нем функции get и post. Не получилось. Прочитал про django-contrib-comments, но его убрали в новых версиях.

Comment: А вам обязательно нужно использовать миксины и классы?

Comment: Нет, я пробовал, но у меня не выводиться форма.

Comment: для CBV нужно переопределить `get_context_data`